# Hibernate 6 interceptor with Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, interceptor

I am upgrading application from Spring Boot 2.7 and Hibernate 5.6 to Spring Boot 3.0 and Hibernate 6.2.

The application has interceptor implementing `org.hibernate.Interceptor` that is registered using `application.yml` and property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor` like this:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ejb:
          interceptor: org.company.MyInterceptor
```

The problem is simple, after performing the upgrade the interceptor stopped working. I haven't read any changes in this regard in Hibernate or Spring Boot changelogs or migration guides, so I am wondering why this isn't working anymore.

I've also read official Hibernate docs and article on Baeldung on interceptors that suggest doing something like this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = getSessionFactoryBuilder(serviceRegistry)
  .applyInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor())
  .build();
```

but since everything is Spring managed and we don't use any code like this directly I am lost at how this should be applied to Spring application

Comment: The javadoc for `Interceptor` says to use `hibernate.session_factory.interceptor` for its registration. Have you tried that instead of using `ejb.interceptor`?